# Web development: Building a graph and running an algorithm

Tags: javascript, graph, clojure, web

I'm very new to web development and I wrote code to take user input from a form, build a graph from it and run a graphing algorithm on it.

At first, I sent the text using a post request but the algorithm sometimes took too long if there were a lot of edges and this resulted in time out error. I'm pretty certain it's not because my code is inefficient.

To fix this I think I have to use javascript instead of sending a request- is this what is usually done with functions that require a lot of time?

**My main question is:** Will I have to rewrite the code in javascript or is there a way to call my original function from javascript?

I'm using clojure...

Comment: So after all of that reading, your question is: How can I call clojure code with JavaScript?

Comment: I doubt that Javascript will be too slow. What exactly is your function supposed to do? Can you express it in O notation? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

Comment: espascarello: I'm sorry- I didn't know whether JavaScript would help or not. I'm still very unsure about web programming in general so I also wanted to know if there were other options in this particular case.

Answer (score 2):

You could program your Javascript in Clojure.

[clojurescript](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript)

Comment: I might try this. I used the java library JGraphT- if clojurescript is compiled to javascript, this means I'll have to change that, right?

Comment: Yes, if you want to use a Java library on the client side it's gonna have to be in an applet.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds more like you need some way to submit the request, have it processed in the background, and then retrieve the results when they are ready - all as separate web requests.

Any HTTP request is going to have a timeout, and the longer it hangs around the better the chance that something in the network is going to cause it to fail.

Most back-end languages provide some way to achieve that; Clojure is great with threads, agents, and similar tools for this.  Restructure your client/server interactions and you shouldn't have to worry about this again.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that I'm curious about is how big the graph is that you're running this algorithm on.  Are you doing something with thousands (or millions) of vertices and edges?  Or is this simply a very expensive algorithm?

Let's assume that handling these requests will naturally take a long period of time, no matter how well coded your algorithm is. Going to javascript isn't strictly speaking the only solution, but it may be the best approach for you.

Options:

1. Run the algorithm, in javascript, on the client machine.  What happens here is that when the user enters the data on the form, the algorithm is run on javascript on the client machine.  Your server is no longer involved, which is nice, because your resources are not being tied up.
2. Increase the timeout time on the server.  Not recommended beyond 20 seconds or so, because people will just end up taxing your server more.
3. Run the algorithm on the server.  Get around the timeout problem using the method that Daniel Pittman suggested: when the user makes a request pass back a request id, and close the connection.  Set up a javascript timeout to make a server request at some moment in the future when you expect the algorithm to have finished running.  If finished, the server returns the results, and this is then rendered.  If not, restart the timer.

So really this comes down to whether you want to make your server or the client's machine do the work.  If the latter, it'll be in javascript, unless you go the route of creating your javascript using clojurescript.  I wouldn't do that for production code just yet, but you can play around with it.

Lastly, whatever you do, make sure you have some widget on the page which indicates to the user that work is being done.  Otherwise, they'll just end up getting frustrated, and hitting the server again (or leaving).